# Wireless Communication between cellphones

Tags: communication, wireless, cellphone, telecommunications

Hypothetically, is it possible to transfer data from 2 devices using a 4g network that's not from their service provider. OR in other words: Could one device download the data from the provider and send it to another a few km away (at the same speed which is why I'm saying the 4G network/band)? (The assumption is both devices can receive and transmit on this network. Would that be realistic if they both could download data from a provider?)

Another question I had was that this would need another band that acts as a channel, or would this "other band" basically need the same data requirements to pass through it, like the downloaded data from the device from the first provider. Essentially is there any difference from channeling the data versus being the provider for the original device that downloaded it.

Curious to hear other thoughts on how I could send data downloaded from one device to another a few miles away (for e.g. on a smart phone without using any other kind of hardware preferably).

Answer (score 3):

It will be possible. But it is not yet. D2D is in 3GPP Release 12, under [*Proximity Services* (ProSe).](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/123300_123399/123303/12.06.00_60/ts_123303v120600p.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

at 1) Theoretically yes, there are no physical laws that would prevent this. **However** a 4G network does not allow it, it is not designed to work like that. So you cannot make this scheme work because you cannot

at 2) Same answer as 1) but also you're assuming that using a different frequency band would help but in practice it will not as providers are assigned certain bands and channels and these are shared between users and also shared over time. So if you're downloading something you aren't using a channel 100% of the time, maybe only 10% so that 10 people can use it. This is also outside of your control and determined by the 4G system.

So forget it, you cannot implement send downloaded data like that, the implementation of the cellular 4G network prevents it. And with good reason as it is how it is intended to be used.

Comment: Also your two phones are very low power compared to the providers towers. They won't be able to see each other over few miles.

Comment: @Cano64 this is the problem with a hotspot/bluetooth/etc. But I couldn't see it being an issue (if you could) using a 4G Band. I mean an RF would be great but the speed is a great hinderance.

Comment: @FakeMoustache do you know of any readings or a link that supports your claim in your answer to 1). I've always thought of the network like a radio frequency kind of scenario. Just curious how it significantly differs

Comment: But using 4G / the 4G band would not solve that ! The increased range comes from the fact that the basestation has more sensitive receivers due to better antenna and higher transmit power also combined with better antennas.

Comment: It was unclear to me that you wanted a handset-to-handset link, I was assuming a handset-basestation-handset link, which is not possible in the current 4G standard. Also handsets cannot behave as a basestation.

Comment: "I've always thought of the network like a radio frequency kind of scenario" It is nothing like that, the radio frequencies are only part of the whole picture. A complete cellular network is **much** more complex than that. To understand it you will have to start with the OSI model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: @FakeMoustache thank you for that, I suppose an implicit part of the question was wondering whether a handset could be a base station or not. But my thinking has always been a handset-basestation- handset set up. I'm just wondering why it's not possible, it's still not very evident to me? (I suppose it's not an easy awnser but just wondering if you have something to point me to).

Comment: handset-basestation- handset is not possible because the 4G system does not allow for it at this moment. Even if "proximity services" were possible then the provider (who is the owner of the basestations) would need to allow it. It is not in their benefit so I doubt if they would allow it.